Emit Traces using OpenTelemetry Java Agent
I am trying to emit traces using opentelemetry dependency in my Spring Boot application. I am expecting to see trace id and span id in the logs. But the trace and span ids are coming as blank.
Dependency used for opentelemetry in pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry.javaagent</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-javaagent</artifactId>
    <version>1.33.5</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

I am using Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.3.2 version.
application.yml
server:
  port: 9090
spring:
  application:
    name: "OpenTelemetry Demo"
logging:
  level:
    com:
      company: DEBUG
  pattern:
    level: "%5p [${spring.application.name},%X{trace_id},%X{span_id}]"

Is there any more dependency which is missing ?

it looks like you're adding the opentelemetry-javaagent as a dependency instead of adding it ad the command line using -javaagent:opentelemetry-javaagent.jar
